# How stop to going to new line in Shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

For Ex :

```
echo "adsa " >> a.txt
echo "asdad " >> a.txt
```

in my file

```
adsa
asdad
```

But i am looking for

```
adsa asdad
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some platforms support `echo -n` to suppress printing newline...  `man echo` might help

Comment: It's more a matter of which shell than which platform (and on some shells it's a matter of whether the relevant option is on). `man echo` is not so much help because it might not warn about the portability issue. [`printf`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3424193/how-stop-to-going-to-new-line-in-shell-script/3424781#3424781) is the way to go.

Comment: I agree. If you want portability, printf is it.

Answer (score 5):

You can also use `printf`:

```
printf "adsa " >> a.txt
printf "asdad " >> a.txt
printf "\n" >> a.txt
```

or

```
printf "adsa " >> a.txt
printf "asdad \n" >> a.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

From echo manpage:

`-n     do not output the trailing newline`

Answer (score 2):

Specifically, `bash` (from OP's tag) has a builtin `echo`which supports `-n`. Try `help echo` from `bash` to see the help for the builtin command